# What is the UX term for sites with aggregated content delivered in an activity feed?

Tags: content

Sites like Pinterest and Mashable have infinite scrolling to the end of the content delivered.

What term describes this type of site?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there is a term for the full site, but the part of the site that delivers the feature you're describing is often called a "Feed" of some kind or another. You could call it a "News Feed," an "Activity Feed," or any other kind of "Feed" and get away with it.

Comment: That is, of course, unless "Feed" follows an animal name.

Comment: Activity Stream might also be used, individual items may well be described as events or actions

Comment: How could I have forgotten "Stream"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good practice to associate the specific implementation of the main page to the whole site.

In the case of Pinterest, `my boards` page is not an infinite scroll.

Pinterest is not an `infinite scroll site`, its main page uses `infinite scroll` to display feeds.

This is in the same way you don't call the stackexcahnge sites `two column site`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many terms that describe this sort of thing. Facebook call it a timeline, email clients often call it a conversation, forum software often calls It a thread. With both facebook and the email clients effort has been made to find exactly the right word to describe what is going on and to use words that are very easy for general users to understand. Technically terms like feed and stream are used for the whole thing and terms like action, activity and event are used for the individual points along the line.

In essence they are all terms that describe the same thing: a set of events, usually those triggered by the actions of human users in a system, organised along a line that represents time. If the concept is stripped to it's most fundamental components even things such as scientific graphs such as those which show species extinction or train timetables will qualify as examples.

It is best to think of the context of your users when picking these terms and trying not to be too jargony. Remember that the terms used for technical development discussions may only be suitable in that narrow and different context.

'infinite scrolling' or 'lazy load' is just a term for a method of displaying lists of information that may or may not be timelines of events, it's a technique that can be used to display search results or product panels for example, as well as activity streams.

In all cases the terms describe a certain element of a site rather than the whole thing.